# Couldn't find catalina.sh

Tags: security, tomcat8, rhel7

I've spent the last 2 hours searching for startup.sh and catalina.sh
as I need to find catalina.sh to add and verify some options, according to the CIS Benchmark.
The problem is that I couldnt find either startup.sh or catalina.sh as shown in the following code :

```
[root@localhost tomcat]# cd bin/
[root@localhost bin]# ls
bootstrap.jar  catalina-tasks.xml  tomcat-juli.jar
```

Even when I try :

```
 [root@localhost /]# locate startup.sh
```

It doesnt give any return.
Did anyone face the same problem already ?

Comment: waht about `sudo find / -name "*catalina*.sh"` ?

Comment: Tried that one and here is the output :   [root@localhost /]# sudo find / -name "*catalina*.sh"
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied

Comment: That is the only line? I lack of ideas... what operating system are you using?

Comment: Yes, it's the only line.. I am using RHEL 7

Comment: either the file is nowhere on the drive (deleted?), either in this folder that even root cannot access... You may try with https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I didn't delete it, Okay lemme see "serverdefault.com" Thank's for your help, though

Answer (score 3):

**Make at least the files `catalina.sh`, `startup.sh` and `shutdown.sh`** inside `bin` executable:

```bash
chmod +x catalina.sh startup.sh shutdown.sh
```

or

```bash
chmod +x bin/*.sh
```

If you are using the `startup.sh`, I may remind you that `catalina.sh` also needs to be executable.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens because the catalina file is not executable
With the following command, you will get the result

```
chmod +x catalina.sh
```